# Find asymptotics of a function

Tags: equation-solving

Can *Mathematica* find the asymptotics of a function in the following sense?

I have

```
Log[1/n^2]/Log[4^(-Sqrt[Log[n]]) + (2^(-Sqrt[Log[n]]) - 1)^2]
```

and I would like to know an asymptotic approximation when $n$ is large.  That is a simple function that is within a constant multiplicative value in the limit when $n \rightarrow \infty$. If instead it was

```
Log[1/n^2]/Log[4^(-Sqrt[Log[n]]) + (2^(-Sqrt[Log[n]]))^2]
```

then I know that

```
Log[1/n^2]/Log[4^(-Sqrt[Log[n]]) + (2^(-Sqrt[Log[n]]))^2]/Sqrt[Log[n]]
```

tends to a constant value.  My question is how could you use *Mathematica* to discover that $\sqrt{\log{n}}$ is the right answer in the second case and to find whatever the right solution is in the first case?

By trial and error I happen to know that the right answer in the first case is somewhere between $2^{\log^{1/2}{n}}$ and $2^{\log^{1/2+\epsilon}{n}}$.

Comment: Could you please put parentheses around `2^-...` and `4^-...` ?

Comment: Done. I hope that is clearer.

Comment: What is connection between 2nd and 3rd formulas?

Comment: You ought to help *Mathematica* ought with some simple analysis first. The solution in the first case looks like $O(2^{\sqrt{\text{Log}[n]}}\text{Log}\left[n\right])$; recognizing this, you can ask *MMA* to take the limit of the ratio for you (demonstrating it is correct and obtaining the constant in the process).

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov, The third is just the second divided by $\sqrt{\log{n}}$.  This is a constant in the limit so $\sqrt{\log{n}}$ is asymptotically equal to the second formula under my definition.

Comment: @whuber, the constant is $1$ :) While waiting to see if someone might find a way to get MMA to suggest the form of the solution, how did you find it by hand?

Comment: I think this is really much easier to do by hand. Expanding the `log` in denominator (after expanding the square), gives to the leading order `-2^(1 - Sqrt[Log[n]])`, which gives the final result to the leading order as  `2^Sqrt[Log[n]] Log[n]`. The log expansion can be done with this code `Expand /@ Log[4^-Sqrt[Log[n]] + (-1 + 2^-Sqrt[Log[n]])^2] /. 
 Log[1 + x_] :> 
  Block[{y}, Normal@Series[Log[1 + y], {y, 0, 1}] /. y -> x]`. (which is a fancy way of saying that `Log[1+x]~x` for small `x`)

Comment: Did not see the comment of @whuber, but what I got agrees with his estimate. The problem for usual expansion is that you have essential singularity, so standard tricks like expanding in `1/Log[n]` around zero don't quite work.

Comment: @Leonid has given exactly the approach I used--except *MMA* wasn't necessary for carrying it out; expanding the logarithm and a reciprocal are so simple you can do it just by looking at the expression. Informally, to get a sense of the asymptotics of something, just identify the terms that dominate the expression's value as $n$ grows large and see what results.

Comment: @whuber I started writing the comment before yours appeared, but then got distracted by attempts to automatically neglect subleading terms, so that manual interference would not be needed. I did not quite succeed, published my comment and then saw yours :))

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the bounty, b.t.w. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first equation, the substitution $z= 2^{\sqrt{\log n}}$ with the inverse relation $n = \exp[ (\log_2 z)^2]$ seems to be worth to try. Note that with $n\to\infty$ also $z\to\infty$. So we try

`sub=Simplify[Log[1/n^2]/
   Log[4^(-Sqrt[Log[n]]) + (2^(-Sqrt[Log[n]]) - 1)^2]
  /. n -> Exp[Log[2, z]^2], z > 1]`

with the result

`-((2 Log[z]^2)/(Log[2]^2 Log[(2 - 2 z + z^2)/z^2])).`

And next

`PowerExpand[Series[sub, {z, \[Infinity], 4}] /. {z -> 2^Sqrt[Log[n]]}]`

which yields the asymptotic expansion

$$\log (n) 2^{\sqrt{\log (n)}}+\frac{2 \log (n)}{3\ 2^{\sqrt{\log (n)}}}+\frac{\log
   (n)}{\left(2^{\sqrt{\log (n)}}\right)^2}+\frac{56 \log (n)}{45 \left(2^{\sqrt{\log
   (n)}}\right)^3}+\frac{4 \log (n)}{3 \left(2^{\sqrt{\log
   (n)}}\right)^4}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{2^{\sqrt{\log (n)}}}\right)^5\right).$$

I believe for the second problem another substitution might do the trick.

Comment: That's very nice, thanks.